# How to list all symbols in current file and search one from the list in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, editor, visual-studio-2022

It's exactly the same function as the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Shift+O in Visual Studio Code.
The closest function in VS is the shortcut Alt+\ do, but it does not list all symbols in current file (this is the key point), and you also need constrain the searching scope to current file.

I use VAX plugin before, I'm looking for the function that shortcut Alt+M in VAX do. VAX is a great pulgin for VS, but I'm not using it now because almost every useful function VAX supplies get a built-in replacement in VS. The only exception is this.

Or can VS list all symbols in current file on sidebar (as a workaround) ? I've searched web for like half an hour but did not get any information for what I need.

Almost every IDE/editor supplies this function, maybe VS is just an exception.

Comment: There is "Go To Symbol" (ctrl 1, ctrl s), but I don't think this is quite what you want.

Answer (score 0):

For a while this has been under either the command 'Edit.GoToSymbol' (for any kind of symbol) or 'Edit.GoToMember' (for methods & functions) that you can configure in the Keyboard settings in Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard.

[image]

You can choose whether you want to search in just the current file, or the entire solution with a small toggle button in the search panel itself (bound to Ctrl+Alt+C in my machine, which I believe must be the default..)

[image]

HOWEVER, if you're using VS 2022 check my other answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77779522/2151254, as recently Microsoft has decided once again to take a decently working feature and shittify it just enough to completely break this workflow.. presumably it was working a bit too well for their liking.