# List function / members of the current document on Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

We can press Alt+\ or Ctrl+T to call out this `Go to members` bar, and click the icon (in the red circle) to restrict the search just in the current document, once we are on VS2019.
[image]

But we lost this feature on VS2022, no `current document` filter anymore. When I type some common function names like "create", there would be tons of them. It's really s**k.

Do you have any suggestion about it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Finally found it (again!) .. it's the nice "New Visual Studio search experience" that you need to disable to go back to the old working behaviour.

You can find it in Tools->Options->Environment->Preview Features..

[image: screenshot of VS settings panel]

Since this is in preview, it'd presumably be part of the "normal" experience at some point, so this answer will surely expire soon.. as usual, great job MS!

Answer (score 0):

The good addon/extension for this is DPack, has better functionality than Visual Studio GUI.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Solved after upgrading to 17.6.5.

Comment: I'm on 17.8.3 and shit is still the same.. gotta love it when "upgrading" means "going backwards"